# Reading Wall Street Journal articles using RSS feed

Tags: c#, jquery, html, rss

I need to build an app that will read WSJ articles using RSS feed (see example feed below).

```
<item>
<title>State Street Net Falls 9.3%</title>
<link>
http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702304432704577349472163975222.html?mod=rss_whats_news_us
</link>
<description>
State Street, one of the largest U.S. trust banks, said first-quarter earnings fell 9.3% on lower fees and revenue from trading services.
</description>
<category>PAID</category>
<pubDate>Tue, 17 Apr 2012 07:56:13 EDT</pubDate>
</item>
```

I have a paid subscription to WSJ however I don't know how to get authenticated against the WSJ site programmatically. For articles that are free I can download them using technology of choice. For a dry run I created a basic console app in C# to grab the content using link in the RSS feed (using HttpWebRequest class in .NET)and it works fine. Frankly, since I am open at this moment about technology in which I will end up developing the app (it's can be JQuery+HTML for web app) so I'm looking for suggestions. If you can point to or share a sample code that will be really helpful.

As asked by someone in the response following is the C# code that download the article.\

```
public virtual string GetHtml(Uri uri)
        {
            try
            {
                var req = ((HttpWebRequest)(WebRequest.Create(uri)));
                string htmlContent;
                using (var wr = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    var response = wr.GetResponseStream();
                    if (null == this.responseUri ) this.responseUri = wr.ResponseUri;
                    Debug.Assert(response != null, "htmlresponse != null");
                    var sr = new StreamReader(response, Encoding.UTF8);
                    htmlContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                 }
                return htmlContent;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @TJHeuvel, As I mention in the original post I need to access the articles from WSJ using the feeds and some of these articles requires authentication and I am no sure how to perform that action.

Comment: In what language, and what have you tried? Where did you fail, what error messages did you get? What have you tried already to resolve those errors? Did you put in any effort?

Comment: @TJHeuvel - Yes, I wrote a C# program to read the article and for free articles that works fine. The problem is when I run it against paid article i get access denied error. Do you want to see C# code?

Comment: What error did you get? This is all vital information, you should include that with your question. The error is the key to finding your solution.

Comment: I have added the code to the original post.